# How can I cash in a small number of delisted US shares? TLAB

Tags: united-states, stocks, stock-exchanges, stock-valuation

How can I find a buyer for old Tellabs shares? This US stock is now delisted.

According to http://www.fiercetelecom.com/story/tellabs-acquired-marlin-equity-partners-891m/2013-10-21 
the company was taken private in 2013.  "... firm will acquire all of Tellabs' outstanding shares for $2.45 per share in cash."

What would be the recommended low cost way to cash in a small number of old shares, for a holder living outside the US and with no current US broker account?

Comment: It it on an OTC list or bankrupt?

Comment: Websearch suggests it was bought out in 2013. Birdcage paper?

Comment: Hi @user662852, According to http://www.fiercetelecom.com/story/tellabs-acquired-marlin-equity-partners-891m/2013-10-21 
the company was taken private in 2013.  "... firm will acquire all of Tellabs' outstanding shares for $2.45 per share in cash."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you held the shares directly, the transfer agent, Computershare, should have had you registered and your address from some point on file.  I have some experience with Computershare, it turned out when Qwest restarted dividends and the checks mailed to the childhood home my parents no longer owned, they were able to reissue all to my new address with one telephone call.  I can't tell you what their international transfer policies or fees might be, but if they have your money, at least its found.

> Transfer Agent
>
> Computershare Investor Services serves as the stock transfer agent for Tellabs. If you need to transfer stock, change ownership, report lost or stolen certificates, or change your address, please contact Computershare Investor Services at +1.312.360.5389.

Comment: Thanks @user662852, that's very useful, gives me a start point.